# OpenCart: Store front shows admin screen

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I have just upgraded my OpenCart 1.5.6 shop to 1.5.6.1 version. The admin page works fine, but when I actually navigate to the store front (catalog), it shows the admin screen (login form). Anybody know what's going on?

It doesn't seem to be redirecting because I don't see `/admin` in the URL when I navigate to the store front.

This is also the new error I'm getting on the store front:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function isLogged() on a non-object in /abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/admin/controller/common/header.php on line 122`

My Admin config:

```
    // HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.website.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.website.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.website.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://www.website.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '******');
define('DB_USERNAME', '******');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '******');
define('DB_DATABASE', '******');
define('DB_PREFIX', '******');
```

My Catalog config:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.website.com/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://www.website.com/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/abs_path/www.website.com/web/content/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', '*******');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', '*******');
define('DB_USERNAME', '*******');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '*******');
define('DB_DATABASE', '*******');
define('DB_PREFIX', '*******');
```

Comment: try to clear cache and truncate your session storage, kill all sessions.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with sessions or caching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you have copied your `config.php` from your `admin/config.php` instead of having your catalog one. Ensure that none of the paths in there have `/admin/` in them. Feel free to post the config.php file to your original post without the sensitive data if you're unsure

Comment: I just added both my config files. Also added the error message I'm getting on the store front. Thanks.

Comment: @farjam: Did you solve this? If it's not the config, the only other thing it could be is you've uploaded the admin controller etc to the catalog folder

Comment: Yes, your guess was correct, it was a wrong config file uploaded to the catalog. Thanks.